# Soap App Delegate error

Tags: iphone

please tell me what this error means:

> /Users/macbook2/Desktop/20/Soap
>   2/MainWindow.xib:3:0 The
>   'viewController' outlet of 'Soap App
>   Delegate' is connected to 'Root View
>   Controllers' but 'RootViewControllers'
>   is not a kind of 'SoapViewController'
>   as specified by the outlet type.

Comment: It is all in there: The kind of the view controller which is connected to an outlet is not the same as the kind of the outlet. Please make clear what exactly you do not understand in this sentence.

Answer (score 2):

It means that you have an instance of UIViewController(SoapViewController) created in App Delegate but you have not changed the class Type of RootViewController in your mainwindow.xib file. Change the classType and then run the code.

Comment: Open your nib file of SoapViewController, select File's Owner, press apple + 4 and change its class type from UIViewController to SoapViewController.